# Java XSL Transformation complaining about binding prefix to namespace

Tags: java, xslt

I try to transform a XML-document which is a TCX-file from a Garmin Watch with XSL and the javax.xml.transform.Transformer. This is the document (shorten):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
    <Activities>
        <Activity Sport="Running">
            <Id>2014-08-23T15:36:15.000Z</Id>
            <Lap StartTime="2014-08-23T11:50:34.000Z">
                <TotalTimeSeconds>3181.0</TotalTimeSeconds>
                <DistanceMeters>7620.0</DistanceMeters>
                <MaximumSpeed>21.887998580932617</MaximumSpeed>
                <Calories>386</Calories>
                <AverageHeartRateBpm>
                    <Value>119</Value>
                </AverageHeartRateBpm>
                <MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                    <Value>167</Value>
                </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
                <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
                <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
                <Track>
                    <Trackpoint>
                        <Time>2014-08-23T11:50:34.375Z</Time>
                        <Position>
                            <LatitudeDegrees>48.17259333333333</LatitudeDegrees>
                            <LongitudeDegrees>10.191565</LongitudeDegrees>
                        </Position>
                        <AltitudeMeters>542.5505981445312</AltitudeMeters>
                        <DistanceMeters>0.0</DistanceMeters>
                        <HeartRateBpm>
                            <Value>70</Value>
                        </HeartRateBpm>
                        <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
                    </Trackpoint>              
            [...]  
                </Track>
                <Notes>Note</Notes>
            </Lap>
            <Notes>Note</Notes>
            <Training VirtualPartner="false">
                <Plan Type="Workout" IntervalWorkout="false">
                    <Name>Running</Name>
                    <Extensions/>
                </Plan>
            </Training>
            <Creator xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Device_t">
                <Name>Polar V800</Name>
                <UnitId>0</UnitId>
                <ProductID>13</ProductID>
            </Creator>
        </Activity>
    </Activities>
    <Author xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Application_t">
        <Name>no application</Name>
    </Author>
</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

I use the javax.xml.transform.Transformer for this task and get a strange error. The transformer gives me the following error message:

> Element "xmlns:xsi" cannot have "xmlns" as its prefix.

It belongs to the line:

```
<Creator xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Device_t">
```

From my point of view, this line is valid. The given namespace is just bound to the prefix xsi. Is it necessary to configure the Transformer to detect it right or do I need to specify something in the xsl-file?

Thanks

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the code you have posted: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTyV/1

Comment: Touchè. Then maybe my problem is the xsl-file. I will check it again and report.

Comment: Perhaps your stylesheet is trying to convert attributes to elements? Anyway, if your program fails with an error then it's usually a good idea to post the code of the program, rather than just giving us its input data.

Comment: Hey Guys, I missed a step in our system. The xml file above is preprocessed before the XSL-Transformation. In this preprocessed file the line above is processed to `<Creator><xmlns:xsi>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xmlns:xsi><type>Device_t</type>`. This causes the error.